# scikit predictions different across executions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I'm trying the following code to study scikit-learn:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB, MultinomialNB

dataset = {
    "data": {
        "chinese beijing chinese",
        "chinese chinese shanghai",
        "chinese macao",
        "tokyo japan chinese",
    },
    "target": np.array([0,0,0,1]),
    "target_names": ["c","c","c","j"]
}

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset["data"])
y_train = dataset["target"]

clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_test = vectorizer.transform(["chinese chinese chinese tokyo japan"])
pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(pred)
```

I know the I'm testing with too little data, but the outputs of several runs are different:

```
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[1]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[1]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
$ python3 teste.py 
[1]
$ python3 teste.py 
[1]
$ python3 teste.py 
[0]
```

I expected that the output would always be "[1]".

is this variable output consequence of the small input dataset? 
or the result should really be fixed as I expected?

I'm using python3 3.4.3, scikit-learn 0.17.1 and numpy 1.11.0.

Comment: I can't recreate this in 3.5.1. Though both the algorithms *should be* deterministic, have you tried `np.random.seed(42)` and `random.seed(42)`?

Comment: I can't recreate this either with the same environment as the poster. Can this question be closed?